# doxygen objective c uml associations for non-public associations with class extensions

Tags: objective-c, doxygen, class-extensions

Doxygen version 1.8.3.1-20130209

Love using Doxygen to generate class diagrams, etc.  Just ran it against some Objective C that has some class extensions with @property declarations using other classes.  It does not seem to be picking these up as UML Associations to the class diagram.

Is there anyway we can get Doxygen to see this?  Newer Version?